# Invoice Magento 2 order with bundle item separately for each bundle selection

Tags: magento2

I have an order for a bundle item which is comprised of 2 products:

- A regular product to be paid at the time the order is placed
- A trial subscription product that will be billed at a later time

At the moment an invoice is created for the entire bundle product cost. Is it possible to programmatically create 2 invoices for the 2 selected bundle products separately to better reflect the time that their payment is received?

Comment: There is an option called "Ship Separately" for bundle items. Have you tried that. This will surely take effect for new orders though. For existing orders, you will have to edit directly to the DB.

Comment: Thanks I will check that out, but it also has to work with virtual products